# PHP mailer in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, phpmailer

I am using php mailer in yii frame work,
can somebody pleas etell me how to include php mailer files in yii framework model to send mail?

following is my code but it is throwing error

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand("update merchant_master set code='$code' where id='$mid'")->execute();

include(Url::base()."/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php");
include(Url::base().'/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php');
include(Url::base().'/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$name= 'Test';
$mail_id ='dev3@mdcconcepts.in';
$idd = 'booking-ticket1475748775322';
$url='<a href="http://www.mdcfestival.com/book-now/uploads/'.$mid.'.pdf" target="_blank">here</a>'; 

return $sendmail = 'dev3@mdcconcepts.in';   
$message="Name:".$name."\r\n";
$message .=" ";
$message .= "EmailId:".$mail_id."\r\n";
$message .=" ";
$message .= "You can get your tickets by clicking this URL: ".$url."\r\n";
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'dev1@mdcconcepts.in';
$email->FromName  = 'MDCFestival';
$email->Subject   = 'MDCFestival Tickets';
$email->Body      = $message;
$email->AddAddress($sendmail);

//$email->AddAttachment($file_name);
if($email->Send()) {
    echo 11;
} else {
    echo 00;
}
```

Comment: Please, add details about the error to the question post.

Comment: @DmitryLozhkin its is throwing internal 500 error

Comment: @DmitryLozhkin i have included this code in model. can you guide me how to include phpmailer library into it

Comment: I would personally not bother by non-yii-wrapped libraries if I were you. SwiftMailer is good option, and it has composer installable version for yii. I assumed you are using yii1 version. In yii2 it comes already with framework. yii1 - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swiftmailer/  yii2 - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html

Comment: Thank you @Ripper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the PHPMailer files inside vendor directory.

And you need to include it in the import array in main.php and console.php

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.vendor.PHPMailer.*',
```

Then you can call it as following in the Controller

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

or there are extensions for Yii 1 and Yii 2, you can easily configure and start sending emails.

Yii 1 - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phpmailer/

Yii 2 - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/zyx-phpmailer/

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense at all:

```
return $sendmail = 'dev3@mdcconcepts.in';
```

The code will never get beyond that point. Change it to:

```
$sendmail = 'dev3@mdcconcepts.in';
```

You should also read the PHPMailer readme that tells you how to load the class files; Use **one** of: composer (preferred), the autoloader, or load the classes manually.